# How to validate the text in both p tags

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<p> expanded state:</p>
<P> true </p>
```

Need to print the text of both tags as one output.

Output as: `expanded state: true`

Comment: Please show parts or your code and the HTML you see

Comment: What code did you try and what did not work?

Comment: Provide more HTML code over here, you can iterate the elements and maintain a List which will have .getText value of webElements, then you can iterate and read the text to validate.

Answer (score 2):

If you are struggling to locate 2 identical elements use square brackets and parentheses to specify which tag you are referring to. E.g:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//p)[2]"));
```

This will get the second p tag on the page. To get the text for printing, use the WebElement method .getText() instead. E.g:

```
String firstElementText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//p)[2]")).getText();
```

[Here is working example I made](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/4c6e3bb0-020f-4c4d-b827-33c7edeb84d5?projectId=examples)

Answer (score 0):

For what you are displaying as HTML:

```
String html = "<p> expanded state:</p>\n" +
              "<p> true </p>";
/* A regular expression to remove all html tags 
   and newlines from string and then trim off 
   leading and trailing whitespaces from string.    */
String result = html.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
System.out.println(result);
```

Will display in the console window:

```
expanded state: true
```